# Override User Registration Page

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I want to override the user registration page, but my code is not working like it used to for Drupal 6.

```
function mytheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );
   $hooks['user_login'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );
   $hooks['user_register'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-register',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );

   return $hooks;
 }
```

Only the login block hook seems to work.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_user_login_block(&$vars) {
  $vars['name'] = render($vars['form']['name']);
  $vars['pass'] = render($vars['form']['pass']);
  $vars['submit'] = render($vars['form']['actions']['submit']);
  $vars['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($vars['form']);
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_register(&$vars) {
  exit;
}
```

I need this to be a preprocess function so I can change/add variables to put into the template. The second function is never called.

Comment: It should use [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7).

Comment: Shouldn't the exit still exit? The login block works.

Comment: If you are using `exit` to check if the preprocess function to see if it gets called, I would suggest to use `watchdog()`; the function uses the constant `WATCHDOG_DEBUG`, which is thought for debugging messages. Using `exit` in a preprocess function doesn't have any visible effect.

Comment: As side note, the first argument of `hook_theme()` is not passed by reference.

Comment: Changing it from drupal_render_children to drupal_render causes it to run out of memory. I am using a starterkit from Omega.

Comment: here is the solution: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/customizing-and-overriding-user-login-page-register-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it: The theme ID should be `user_register_form`, not `user_register`. Now it works.